# sp::proj4string(obj) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output in R

Tags: r, r-sp, rgdal, tmap, proj

I am trying to plot a map using `tmap` library:

```
library("rgdal")
library("tmap")
area_dnipro <- readOGR("dnipro.shp", encoding = "UTF-8", use_iconv=TRUE)
tm_shape(area_dnipro) + tm_polygons()
```

But during plotting I am getting this message:

```
Warning message:
In sp::proj4string(obj) : CRS object has comment, which is lost in output
```

Can anybody clearly explain the meaning of this message? Why does library (I guess `sp`) outputs this for me? Something wrong with my shp-file? Can I do something in order not to get this warning? - May be transform my shape-file somehow? Because I am plotting this map from RStudio to HTML and don't want this text in the resulting HTML:

[image: tmap plot]

Here are my shape-files: [download](https://easyupload.io/xhw4e7)

P.S. I am aware about this [topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364667/r-4-0-1-not-sure-i-understand-this-message-warning-message-in-proj4stringx) but it doesn't shed light on this problem (at least for me). I don't understand what is the problem and what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `sf` package to read the shapefile:

```
R> area_dnipro <- sf::read_sf("dnipro.shp")
R> tm_shape(area_dnipro) + tm_polygons()
```

this does not show the warning.

See also `?tm_shape`:

shp: shape object, which is an object from a class defined by the ‘sf’ or ‘stars’ package. Objects from the **packages ‘sp’** and ‘raster’ **are also supported, but discouraged.**